# Unable To Trigger Invalidate Cache in rtk query using tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

This is my Api.js

```
 export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',

  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const userInfo=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
    // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
    if (userInfo!==null) {
     headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`)
   }
   // console.log("logingheaders",headers)
   return headers 
  }
}),
 tagTypes:['Refetchorders'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMyOrders:builder.query({
  query:()=>{
      return{
        url:`/api/orders/myorders`,
        method:'GET',
        provideTags:['Refetchorders']
      }
  }
)}
)}
```

so whenever the user hit logout iam triggering api call to reset cache with calling
getmyorders

```
  const[getMyOrders,getMyOrdersResult]=useGetMyOrdersQuery(skipToken);
   const logoutHandler=()=>{
    getMyOrders()
    navigate('/')
```

}

the logout handler is in header which loads when home screen is loaded
the error i am seeing is

```
    Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `useGetMyOrdersQuery` as if it were `useGetMyOrdersLazyQuery` here.

Correct usages would either be

```js
const getMyOrdersResult = useGetMyOrdersQuery(skipToken);
```

or

```js
const [getMyOrders, getMyOrdersResult] = useGetMyOrdersLazyQuery();
```

As you are directly navigating away from that site when you trigger that query, I would question if you need any of them. Fetching data required on the next site should be the responsibility of the next site - not of the site you're navigating away from.